# Como retirar o slider automatico do carousel do bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, slide, carousel

Como retirar o slide automatico do carousel do Bootstrap? Tenho um carousel que está funcionando perfeitamente, porém preciso com que ele fique estático e só mude as imagens quando clicar nas setas a direita ou a esquerda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false
});
```

Comment: cara, coloquei o código como vc falou mas ainda está mudando sozinho:

Comment: cara, coloquei o código como vc falou mas ainda assim não funcionou: <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: false,
        });
    </script>

Comment: Eu acho que tem a haver com o nome da classe que tem no seu caroussel

Comment: Se puder complete a pergunta com a primeira parte do html do seu carousel sff. Depois eu ajusto a minha resposta

Comment: Qual é a versão do seu bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.6. Coloquei o javascript editado e ainda nada.

Comment: Editei, tente assim

Comment: Nada ainda. Continua mudando o slide

Comment: Dá algum erro na sua consola?

Comment: Testei: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/2428/ . Resultou aqui

Comment: Cara, errou infantil. Eu tava colocando o script la no head e declarei o jquery la embaixo. Agora funcionou, valeu

Answer (score 2):

Apenas adicionar o atributo data-interval e digitar o valor 0 (false):

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="0">
```